# Significant figures in a calculation of atomic mass from isotopic abundance

Tags: analytical-chemistry, significant-figures

I had this question:

> Naturally occurring europium consists of two isotopes with a mass of 151 and 153. Europium-151 has an abundance of 48.030 and, and europium-153 has a natural abundance of 51.970. What is the atomic mass of europium? **Do not include units. Be sure to round to the correct number of significant figures.**

So I do the math for the calculation:
$(151 \times 0.48030)+(153 \times 0.51970) = 152.0394$ 
I submit 152.0 because, as I understand it, the products of the math in the parentheses should be considered to have 3 sig figs each - ending in the tenths place. So when I add those two sums up, it should end in the tenths place too given addition/subtraction sig figs rules. This is marked as incorrect, and I worry I am misunderstanding something.

I emailed the professor, and he said it was a word question and I needed only to select the fewest sig figs of the ones provided (151 and 153 have 3), so my answer should have been 152 without the 0 in the tenths place. Is this usually the case? What confuses me is I don't think I was allowed to do this for other word problems, but I could be wrong. Is there a difference between word problems and other problems, and is 3 really the amount of sig figs I should have had?

Comment: Teachers should not be torturing students with significant figure rules. They should rather teach common sense and critical reasoning in science rather than impose significant figure rules as heavenly rules. No wonder chemistry doesn't attract the brightest rather than repels them. Nobody does research with atomic mass measurements like this. I have Linus Pauling' General Chemistry Textbook (Two Nobel Prizes), and it does not even mention these these type of calculations.

Comment: Anyway, use significant figures as "common sense". These are approximate rules and the idea is that do not use unnecessary numbers *once* you quote the answer. Rounding off should be done at  *end* of all calculations. There is nothing such as sig fig rules for word problems etc.

Comment: "*Do not include units*" in a question with all quantities being *dimensionless* as well as omitted percent sign at the natural abundance value are troubling signs. As for the sig figs, your professor pretty much explained it all right and I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect on top of that. The thing is, significant figures are supposed to be studied in a math class *prior* to chemistry and physics (because they belong to numerical analysis) so that the questions like "*do sig figs depend on the type of question*" don't even arise.

Comment: Don't use an asterisk for multiplication in displayed formulas and don't omit leading zeros. Try to make title that is concise and reflects what's exactly being asked for. Never use pointless "*question about*".

Comment: IMHO, this case is a typical example of a task made up for a sake of the task, with rather weird up to ridiculous formulation. They should use rather real life example with meaningful numbers and approach. E.g. volumetry with uncertainties of mass, volume and concentration.

Comment: @andselisk The issue is I feel like I'm getting mixed messages from the professor, and I don't feel like pressing him for an explaination I can apply more easily will serve me. Hence why I was looking for advice from people more familiar with this. YouTube videos didn't answer my specific questions. If I had to do a calculation to solve the problem, would I not normally have to use the multi-step solution (explained) he taught previously? I definitely would have been great to have previous knowledge before the class, but I didn't know what I didn't know. Thanks for the advice on formatting.

Comment: This is somewhat of a trick question by not giving the atomic masses correctly but abundances to great precision with no indication that this has been done. The correct way according to 'What is the atomic mass of europium? ' would be to look up accurate masses and use error propagation to work out summed values of then truncate error depending on number of decimal places used in masses and percentages. etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what clumsily missing the per signs is actually a troubling sign for, but feel free to go into more detail about that, about what students should ideally be taught before chemistry, about formatting, or whatever. Or just answer my question. To reiterate: when calculating the atomic mass of europium, using the specific numbers provided in the question, how many significant figures is appropriate? Since my professor specifically mentioned this is a 'word question,' I'm trying to figure out if there are special rules that make the logic in my initial conclusion (152.0) faulty.

Comment: Because I don't see how, as long as the word problem involved me doing calculations, I wouldn't go with the significant figures from my calculation. These were his exact words: all you needed to do was look at the significant figures of the given (least). 151 and 153 were both listed as 3 significant figures.

Comment: So is this a matter of academic rules regarding word problems or how you're normally supposed to handle significant figures? Or am I actually calculating things wrong. If it's the latter, a more thorough explanation would be appreciated. Circumstances mean I don't feel comfortable nagging at my professor for explainations.

Comment: Putting the task ridiculousness aside, IMHO the expected procedure is this:  isotope masses have 3 sig figs. Multiplied by numbers with more sig figs keeps these 3 sig figs. So does the summation. The result with 3 sig figs is 152. ( as said, ridiculousness aside ). Round up just the final result not to cummulate rounding errors.

Comment: Are we intended to treat the 151 and 153 as exact values, i.e., mass numbers for the purposes of this calculation? I wouldn't say yes, but it's not exactly clear from the intent of the question. When dealing with things that could well be exact integers, it is the responsibility of the question asker to be explicit about that...

Answer (score 1):

First, for reasons I'll point out later this is a poorly made-up problem which was only designed to test significant figures, not to teach anything real about chemistry.

Second there are no special rules for "word problems" using significant figures.

The gist is that significant figures are a simple method to do error propagation in calculations. It is essentially based on the notion that the error is +/- 1/2 of the last significant digit, as if the value had been rounded to that digit. So 151 means that the value should be between 150.5 and 151.5.

The whole point of significant figures is to prevent you from dividing 151 by 3.00 and getting some ridiculous precision like 50.333333333333333333333333333333.

Now on to the problem. 151 and 153 are mass numbers for the europium  isotopes. Mass numbers are poor values to use for the [isotope  masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_europium). If fact the known masses are 150.9198502(26)  and 152.9212303(26). The numbers in parenthesis give the standard deviation of the measurement. So for 150.9198502 the standard deviation is 0.0000026.

Likewise according to the Wikipedia page, $\ce{^{151}Eu}$ has an abundance of 0.4781(6) and $\ce{^{153}Eu}$ has an abundance of 0.5219(6). The point is that the isotopic variation in samples taken from all over the earth limits the precision of the atomic mass for any element, not the mass of the isotopes which are know with much greater precision.

The same Wikipedia page linked earlier gives the atomic mass of europium as 151.964(1) which is inconsistent with the given percentages. I do not know the how/why there are so many more significant figures in the atomic mass (*and I am too lazy to turn this answer into a research project to figure that part out...*).

Comment: *....limits the precision of the atomic mass for any element....*    While elements with odd atomic number have maximally 2 stable isotopes, some of them have just 1, like 19F or  23Na. In these cases, atomic mass is known with precision of isotopic mass.